# Windows 10 unable to access "This PC" in file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, troubleshooting

When I click on "This PC" under Windows file explorer it attempts to open, the green bar at the top of the Window gets to about halfway, the screen flickers and closes file explorer in entirely. I also can not run any applications that aren't Powershell as Administrator. Also, creating a new profile gives me an error when I attempt to log in "Profile Service has failed to load the profile"

1. Thinking the harddrive could be on the fritz, I copied the whole drive to a new identical drive. Booted on new drive, issue still persisted.
2. Tried booting into Safe mode, issue still persisted.

Lastly after doing some research I used PowerShell running it as an Administrator I used the Repair Windows Image followed on this Link
[system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93)
Issue still persisted.

Has anyone encountered this issue? I haven't tried a restore or advanced booting options yet. I am thinking the OS could be corrupt? But like I said I have ruled out a hardware issue at this point.

UPDATE: I went into my event logs, under here I am getting an error "Faulting application name explorer.exe. Faulting process ID 0x1718.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has anyone encountered this issue?

I have had this issue in the past and it was caused by an HDD causing hundreds of I/O error events.  The problem would be intermittent at first then the behavior morphed into long unexplained delays processing mouse clicks, and eventually, Windows wouldn't boot at all.

> I am thinking the OS could be corrupt?

I would agree.  The installation likely is corrupt, it likely is in a state that cannot be repaired, due to the storage device being in a near or failing state.

> I went into my event logs, under here I am getting an error "Faulting application name explorer.exe. Faulting process ID 0x1718.

So explorer.exe is crashing, this is the reason the screen flickers, and partially the reason you are unable to run any other program.  If you were to look at additional event logs, you would likely see, application event logs for other programs indicating the same error.

> Lastly after doing some research I used PowerShell running it as an Administrator I used the Repair Windows Image followed on this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93%20Issue%20still%20persisted).

You should avoid using SFC on Windows 8+, `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` is the command you should be using, but if no problems were fixed or found then the command, there isn't anything you can do. The DISM and SFC tools cannot detect and all system integrity issues.

> creating a new profile gives me an error when I attempt to log in "Profile Service has failed to load the profile"

Since you are unable to use Safe Mode, no integrity issues are being detected, and you are unable to create a new user profile to diagnose potential software incompatibilities your only recourse is to reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: So why does this issue persist on a new hardrive, corrupt system files being moved over to a new drive therefore the issue still persists? Would a system restore be an option?

Comment: A system restore or reinstallation is a solution. For the rest you answered your own question, you copied a corrupt system to a new drive, of course it kept the errors.

Comment: It's not "Of course" It's the next necessary step. I did all my diagnostics before reaching here, this was the next step...